# Emails not sending to some addresses when using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on a PHP application that generates a unique profile code and QR code and sends them automatically via email in an HTML format when a profile is registered. I'm using PHPMailer. It sends successfully to some email accounts and delivers in Junks on some email clients; Outlook and Hotmail. Below is the mailing script

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = gethostname();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'info@domain.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'Company Name');
$mail->addAddress($email, $first_name);
$mail->addCC('email@gmail.com', 'Full Name'); //Optional ; Use for CC
$mail->addCC('email2@domain.com', 'Second Company Name'); //Optional ; Use for CC
$mail->addCC('info3@domain.com', 'Third Company Name'); //Optional ; Use for CC
$mail->Subject = 'Title Goes Here';
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$annlogo = 'assets/img/logo-for-app.png';
$email_template = 'email_template.html';
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($file, 'qrimg');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($annlogo, 'logoimg');
$message = file_get_contents($email_template);
$message = str_replace('%recipientname%', $first_name, $message);
$message = str_replace('%uniqueid%', $userID, $message);

$mail->MsgHTML($message);    

$mail->send();
```

What could be wrong? Is the problem from my end or from the email server end?

Comment: Now what, is the message not sent sometimes as you initially claim or is "junk" delivered as you later claim? Make up your mind ...

Comment: Your first port of call should always be [the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters).